# Rotate 2 images on separate timers

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to rotate 2 separate images in the same macro on different timers. I want them to start at the same time, but rotate at different speeds. I have been able to get them to rotate together, but only at the same speed. My attempt to get them to separate as caused them to run, at best, one before the other, or the second one does not rotate at all

My code currently looks like:

```
Sub macro()

    rep_count = 0

    Do
    DoEvents

        rep_count = rep_count + 1

        Sheet1.Shapes("Little Clock").Rotation = rep_count
        timeout (0.01)
        Loop Until rep_count = 360

    Do
    DoEvents

        Sheet1.Shapes("Big Clock").Rotation = rep_count
        timeout2 (0.01)
        Loop Until rep_count = 360

End Sub

Sub timeout(duration_ms As Double)
    Start_Time = Timer
    Do
    DoEvents
        Loop Until (Timer - Start_Time) >= 0.1
End Sub

Sub timeout2(duration_ms As Double)
    Start_Time = Timer
    Do
    DoEvents
        Loop Until (Timer - Start_Time) >= 0.7
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you really need two timers? Say the big clock rotates twice as fast as the little clock ... you only need one timer, but on each iteration of your `do loop`, you rotate the small clock half as much as you rotate the big clock. So you end up with one `timeout` sub, and one `do loop`. Your problem is that both loops cannot run simultaneously as Excel Vba is not multi-threaded.

Comment: I didn't need two timers. I didn't realize I could set one of the clocks to rotate based on the speed of the other clock. That made everything much simpler and worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

Normal Module :

```
Public c As clsTimer

Sub Button1_Click()

    Set c = New clsTimer
    Set c.s1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(1)
    Set c.s2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(2)
    c.start 1, 2        

End Sub
```

and a class module, `clsTimer`

```
Public s1 As Shape
Public s2 As Shape

Public Function start(lngInterval1 As Long, lnginterval2 As Long)

Dim s As Long
Dim lngSecCount As Long

ResetTimer:

s = Timer

Do Until Timer > s + 1
    DoEvents
Loop

lngSecCount = lngSecCount + 1

If lngSecCount Mod lngInterval1 = 0 Then s1.Rotation = s1.Rotation + 1
If lngSecCount Mod lnginterval2 = 0 Then s2.Rotation = s2.Rotation + 1

GoTo ResetTimer

End Function
```